# how can I avoid pairing up bluetooth keyboard booting different operating systems

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

do you have any suggestions for someone like me who keeps multiple operating systems on their machines?

I have this annoyance with the bluetooth keyboard, I have to re-pair everytime I reboot into another operating system.

I know that there are some dongles that can persist the connection even at POST levels, anyone have experience in this regard?

Comment: What model keyboard you are using and What OS you have?

Comment: apple bluetooth keyboard, windows 10, ubuntu, sierra hackintosh